# drawing with clear color on UIView (cutting a hole) in static method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, core-graphics

I have an iPhone application and I need to implement the following method:

```
+(UITextView *)textView:(UITextView *) withCuttedRect:(CGRect)r
```

This method must cut (fill with `[UIColor clearColor]`) the rect `r` from `UITextView` and return `UITextView` object.

The user will see the view behind `UITextView` from the cutted holes.

How can it be done?

Comment: Maybe I should use quartzcore and it's `setBackground` filters method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you would have something like:

```
 +(UITextView *)textView:(UITextView *)textView withCuttedRect:(CGRect)r {
}
```

you actually can simply access the textview's layer from core animation with

```
 textView.layer
```

What you then can to is set a mask for clipping. These masks work the following way: you generally draw a black shape, and that stays the same, the rest will be clipped (ok, you actually can also do some things on the alpha channel but roughly that is it).

So you need a black rectangle as a mask, with a rectangle within the rectangle which is free. for that you can approximately do

```
 CAShapeLayer *mask = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
 mask.frame = self.textView.layer.bounds;
 CGRect biggerRect = CGRectMake(mask.frame.origin.x, mask.frame.origin.y, mask.frame.size.width, mask.frame.size.height);
 CGRect smallerRect = CGRectMake(50.0f, 50.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f);

 UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[maskPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMinY(biggerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMaxY(biggerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMaxY(biggerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMinY(biggerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(biggerRect), CGRectGetMinY(biggerRect))];

[maskPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMinY(smallerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMaxY(smallerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMaxY(smallerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMinY(smallerRect))];
[maskPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(smallerRect), CGRectGetMinY(smallerRect))];

 mask.path = maskPath.CGPath;
[mask setFillRule:kCAFillRuleEvenOdd];
 mask.fillColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
 self.textView.layer.mask = mask;
```

The code above is also disused by [Crop a CAShapeLayer retrieving the external path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856353/crop-a-cashapelayer-retrieving-the-external-path)

The idea why that filling works that way is nicely explained in [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-DontLinkElementID_10) in the section "Filling a Path"

Comment: Nice! And just a note, for doing the same with a `CGContext`, you add the path the same as you did, and then you fill it with `CGContextEOFillPath(context)`. :) Where EO means even odd, not to be confused with EndOfFile (which is how it scans for me).

Comment: You can trim off a few lines of code here by using `[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:biggerRect]` instead of the basic `[UIBezierPath bezierPath]`.  This will initialize the maskPath with the biggerRect pre-added.  That way you only need to use moveToPoint: and addLineToPoint: to add the second rect.