# Create camera overlay for read QR code

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, overlay, qr-code

I am working an application which is using QR code reading functionality, but i want to make a overlay on camera, like some portion of camera will read the QR code and other view on screen will show with blur effect, suppose over screen size is `375*667` so camera will open on center of the view will frame size

```
X: 64pt
Y: 210pt
W: 247.5pt
H: 247.5pt
```

which can read the code, and other portion of screen will be with transparent  blur effect.

Comment: Are you using AVFoundation Framework?

Comment: @Chetan sharma, in` oc ` you can use:https://github.com/MxABC/LBXScan    in `swift` you can use https://github.com/MxABC/swiftScan

Comment: Use Zbar Thirdparty Framework  for both QR code and bar code scanner which may help You

Answer (score 2):

Maybe these tutorials will help you:

- [YouTube Tutorial by "Jared Davidson" about Custom Camera Views](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0O3ZGUS3pk)
- [App Coda Tutorial about how to create a barcode reader app (contains information about AVFoundation)](http://www.appcoda.com/simple-barcode-reader-app-swift/)

> The **AV Foundation Framework** provides the tools that we will use to build our barcode reader. Here’s a little rundown of what’s involved
>   in the process.
>
> **AVCaptureSession** will manage data form the camera – input to output.
>   The **AVCaptureDevice** is the physical device and its properties.
>   **AVCaptureSession** receives input data from the **AVCaptureDevice**.
>   **AVCaptureDeviceInput** captures data from the input device.
>   **AVCaptureMetadataOutput** forwards metadata objects to be processed by a
>   delegate object.

Maybe this will help:
[How to add a blur mask with a custom shape above a dynamic camera view in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662931/how-to-add-a-blur-mask-with-a-custom-shape-above-a-dynamic-camera-view-in-swift)

Comment: Thanks to share, but my problem is not how to read bar code, i want to create that Blur UI around the camera view in iPhone screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can create QR reader with AVFoundation using AVCaptureSession. Tutorial and whole code is available at [this link](http://www.appcoda.com/intermediate-swift-tips/qrcode-reader.html)

This sample code has blue box as overlay. You can create any image (with transparent part where camera input can be shown) and add that as overlay.

Comment: Thanks to share, but this is not as i want to do.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your using the `Image Picker` currently? You should probably transition to using `AVCaptureSession` with `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` this will allow you to fully customise the UI around the camera as you are just adding the layer to any UIView.