# Inverse CGPath in Rect

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, cgpath

I'm looking to inverse a `CGPath` (relative to a Rect). By this, I mean I have defined a `CGPath` and I want to get a `CGPath` that outlines all other areas in the rect.

I've been experimenting different ways and been googling for a couple days now with no luck. I simply just cannot work it out!

Consider the following rect with defined `CGPath` (where green is the defined `CGPath` filled):

[image]

Now, with what I want (the inversed `CGPath`) would produce the following:

[image]

Specifically, this is for usage with an `SKCropNode` and `SKPhysicsBody` in the SpriteKit framework, however i'm producing the polygon for the mask node using `CGPaths` (and storing the path in an ivar).

**Is inversing a `CGPath` possible, or some other way? If so, how?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10856353/608157)?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist: It *looks* as if the original path uses 2 circles and the *non-zero winding rule* for filling it. In that your method would not produce the wanted result, as it relies on the even-odd winding rule.

Answer (score 5):

I copied the code from the answer @DavidRonnqvist linked to, but changed it to retrieve the UIBezierPath from a CGPath, which is what you need:

```
CGPath        filledPath = ...; //This is the inner filled shape
CAShapeLayer *invertedLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:filledPath];

[invertedLayer setPath:[maskPath CGPath]];
[invertedLayer setFillRule:kCAFillRuleEvenOdd];
[invertedLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor colorOfYourChoice] CGColor]];
```

I didn't test this but in theory it should work.

Comment: An important tool in getting this approach to work correctly is `+[UIBezierPath bezierPathByReversingPath]`. When working with the EO fill rule, it is important to keep track of whether you are drawing clockwise or counterclockwise. By reversing paths, you can generally get the behaviors you want (for paths you totally control). See "Filling a Path": https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html

Comment: Thanks to all for answers so far - i'm just having trouble trying to figure out how I would apply all of this to SpriteKit node objects... anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Code sample, using `UIBezierPath.reversing()`:

```
let cgPath: CGPath = ...
let size = cgPath.boundingBox.size

let inverted = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
inverted.append(UIBezierPath(cgPath: cgPath).reversing())

//draw result
let image = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { context in
    context.cgContext.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
    context.cgContext.addPath(inverted.cgPath)
    context.cgContext.fillPath()
}
```