# Masking a view so it only appears outside of a closed Bezier Path

Tags: uiview, mask, uibezierpath

I have a closed Bezier Path. It is currently masking a UIView in the normal way, meaning that only the parts of the view that are within the bounds of the path are visible. I have now decided on an aesthetic feature that would be very easy to implement if there were a way to anti-mask with the same bezier path. What I mean is that now I would like a different UIView, which is currently totally visible outside of the path, to be cut off as soon as it intersects with the Bezier Path. Is there a way to set the mask of this other UIView to be the inverse of the Bezier Path?

Comment: do you want a view which only shows the portion which is outside of path and not inside?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crop a CAShapeLayer retrieving the external path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856353/crop-a-cashapelayer-retrieving-the-external-path)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856353/crop-a-cashapelayer-retrieving-the-external-path/10881680#10881680

Answer (score 0):

lets say the instance of view which has to be masked be maskedView(mview -red color).
And lets say there is a backgroundView(bview - green) which is below this maskedView.
If you just mask the view, then the area inside of path of maskedView will be visible and the area outside of path will be filled with backGroundView.

[image]

So, we say mView is masked while bview is in the background.**Another way of saying is that bView is front and is anti-masked while mview is down of bView.** Eventhough we apply mask to mView, **the screen appears to us that bView is anti - masked**.

So, we create such an illusion for anti-masking a view.

**programatic explanation:**
*view1 - anti mask this view (green color view of image)

view2 - backgroundView  (red color view of image)*

```
*[self.view addSubview:view1];
*[self.view insertSubview:view2 aboveSubview:view1];
//now view2 is top of view1
*apply bezier path to view2 not view1.
```

Hope this helps.